# Anchor tag not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, anchor

I have a simple anchor tag in my page that works with Chrome, Safari and Firefox except for IE. I have the IE11.

Based on various comments online I've tried everything from display: block; to specifying text within anchor tag.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="top" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</div>
<section class="prices-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="prices left">
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: In IE when I click on the link which is supposed to take me to a specific location on the page, it takes me to the top of the page instead. It works well on other browsers.

Comment: There's no anchor (`<a>`) tag in that code.

Comment: So I tried <a id="top" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</a> and still the same problem appears.

Comment: There is no link in the anchor-tag

Comment: You know... It'd be helpful if you closed your `<div>` tags...

Comment: I just pasted the top portion of the HTML. They do have closing tags.

Comment: Also, the section tag is not supported in IE11. It's only supported as far as IE 9.

Comment: <section class="prices-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="prices left">
            <h3></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

Comment: <a id="top" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</a>
<section class="prices-wrapper"> 
<div class="content"> <div class="prices left">
<h3></h3> 
</div> 
</div> 
</section>

Comment: @Brendan really? [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp) suggests support for it only *appeared* in IE9.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Sorry. @TZHX

Comment: Check out this link which also includes browser support for the `<section>` tag. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp

Answer (score 3):

This just bit me, too: **"top" is apparently a reserved word in Internet Explorer**. In other words, this will not work in IE:

```
<p><a name="top">My Top Section</a></p>
...
<p><a href="#top">Jump to top</a></p>
```

but this will:

```
<p><a name="up">My Top Section</a></p>
...
<p><a href="#up">Jump to top</a></p>
```

... and yes, the *only* difference between those is the name of the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<a name="top"></a>` as your anchor, then link to it like: `<a href="#top">Go to top</a>`.

Notice that you should set the `name` attribute of the first anchor tag, not the `id` as you do on the div in your example.

Complete example, tested in IE 11.0.9600.17498 and working as intended:

```
<html>
<body>
<a name="top"></a>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<a href="#top">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried name too and it doesn't work just in IE
<a name="top" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</a>

The link is set in code behind as:
tabs.Href = tab.Paths.Path + "#top";

Comment: Just set it to `#top` without anything else.

Comment: I tried just adding #top and it actually took me where I intend to go. The problem is, I have to add a path before the #top because I am switching to another tab within the page. Could it be that when the page posts back and refreshes, the #top anchor is lost? @TZHX

Comment: @TZHX, did you actually try your suggestion? Because using the specific  name `top` will prevent the anchor from working in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Martha I did try it, yes. Two years ago.

Comment: @Martha And again, now, in version 11.0.9600.18538 -- and it still works as intended as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and (through chance more than anything!) discovered if you number the id tag it works! So for your code:

```
<div id="1-top" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Hope this helps anyone!